# Python Image Wiggle with 2 Files

Tags: python, canvas

I'm working on a piece of code to write a program that allows me to select 2 image files, then enter into a loop that copies the images successively onto a visible canvas on top of each other as fast as possible. I'm trying to create an infinite loop.

I thought this would work, but I think there's an error in selecting files and copying them correctly onto the canvas.

Here's what I've done so far...

```
def Main():
    Canvas = makeEmptyPicture(600,400)
    
repaint(Canvas)
    Filename = pickAFile()        
    Canvas = makePicture(Filename)        
    Canvas2 = duplicatePicture(Canvas1)        
    copyInto(Canvas2, Canvas1, X, Y)
```

EDIT: (image of code removed for brevity).

Comment: I improved the formatting of the question, included the image and did some spelling fixes.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't get it formatted like that for some reason.